# How can I create Umbraco Navigation using .NET Control instead of Xslt

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco and have been able to get through most basic things. I am able to setup a site and and content already. However, I'd like to create my navigation with .NET control instead of using Xslt but I am stuck with relative little knowledge of Umbraco yet. Thanks.

Comment: Technically you should have been able to use the standard SiteMap api provided by asp.net, but since Umbraco's implementation of a SiteMap provider is pretty broken i can't recommend going down that path since it will just give you problems later regarding to preview-mode and stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this using API of umbraco. You can use them in your User control by Referencing the DLL's and importing namespaces.

E.g for your work.

umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node Mynode = new umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node(NodeIdOfYourParent);

```
 NodeIdOfYourParent = Node id of your Root node from where you want to begin traversal.
```

umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Nodes MychildrenNodes = node.children;

yourRepeater.DataSource = childrenNodes;
yourRepeater.DataBind();

```
![alt text][1]
```

This way you can do the same.

Kind Regards,
Jigar

P.S Just delivered TheJoint.com and individual and have 5 project completion in umbraco. Jigar.Mca@gmail.com.

Comment: Hi Jigar, can you make it clearer how I can get the complete nodelist for the navigation so that I can then iterate (recurse if necessary) them and render them the way I want.  For example what you do assume by 'NodeIdOfYourParent'?

Comment: Hi GBoyega i have updated the answer. feel free to email me on developerjigar@gmail.com for any problem, Send me snap also.